# Update table with inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables shown below

```
BidID   CreatedDate              BidVersionNumber
2       2018-05-17 04:35:40.320    AB25443/01-01
3       2018-06-11 03:36:59.977    AB25443/01-01
```

Second Table

```
BidVersionNumber       CreatedDate        BidId
 AB25443/01-01       5/17/2018 4:35:40
 AB25443/01-01       5/17/2018 4:41:10
```

I want to update the BidId of the second table by joining with the first table on BidVersionNumber but since the BidVersionNumber is the same I also want to match on CreatedDate joining just on the 4:35:40 part of the time. Can someone please tell me how to join on two columns.

Desired output

```
BidVersionNumber       CreatedDate        BidId
 AB25443/01-01       5/17/2018 4:35:40     2
 AB25443/01-01       5/17/2018 4:41:10     3
```

Comment: *joining just on the 4:35:40* but this doesn't work for the second row. How does it get BidId = 3?

Comment: @scsimon he means that he wants to join on `CreatedDate` but ignore the milliseconds in the JOIN.

Comment: Right @TabAlleman but for that second row, the hour, minute, and second doesn't match. Or eve the date for that matter, but expected output has it updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tricky part here is the time comparison.  One method of doing this is by subtracting a second from the `t1` time and essentially using `between`:

```
update t2
    set bidId = t1.BidId
    from table2 t2 join
         table1 t1
         on t2.BidVersionNumber = t1.BidVersionNumber and
            t2.CreatedDate <= t1.CreatedDate and
            t2.CreatedDate > dateadd(second, -1, t1.CreatedDate);
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon..Always helpful :)